# How to verify if the function mssql_query() is working

Tags: php

I have a database sql server and I am using php as programming language. Before, all were working. After executing a "truncate" in my table, I can't insert anymore.

I want to know a way to verify if my function mssql_query() is working or not.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple check:

```
// $conn - connection resource
// $sql - sql query string
mssql_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error occured!");
```

or more complex:

```
mssql_query($conn,$sql);

if (!mssql_query) {
    // The query has failed, print a nice error message
    // using mssql_get_last_message()
    die('MSSQL error: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

Comment: exactly this! the first example helped me!

Comment: You never should kill the application. Throw an exception etc

Comment: ideally - yes, but if it executes at the end of the script, you can use `die`. It will depend on execution context

Comment: Don't agree. The end of the script can move once there are more than 1 developer ;)

Comment: so what? The next developer should change the logic(add/remove die/exception) if he moves the execution context

Comment: it's only a simple test